# global name 'old_price' is not defined

Tags: python, django-models, django-templates

on my url(/products/dress-shirt/), I got the following  error.

```
"NameError at /product/dress-shirt/
global name 'old_price' is not defined"
```

while i've defined 'old_price' inside a function 'sale_price' in my models.py

```
def sale_price(self):
    if old_price > self.price:
        return self.price
    else:
        return None
```

And my template code is:

```
{% if p.sale_price %} 
Was: <del>$ {{ p.old_price }}</del>
<br />
Now: $ {{ p.price }}
{% else %} 
Price: $ {{ p.price }}
{% endif %}
```

and 'old_price' variable is defined in models as

```
class Product(models.Model):
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 9, decimal_places=2)
old_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, blank=True , default=0.00)
```

posting relevant code only.

Comment: where you defined `old_price` variable in `sale_price` function??

Comment: `if old_price > self.price:` you are using `old_price` varaible value.

Comment: How do you think you've defined old_price? You haven't, you've simply referenced it. Where do you think the value will be coming from?

Comment: I've posted the models code above where i've defined 'old_price' variable.

Comment: But can't you see the difference in how you're referencing "price" vs "old_price" in that view code?